# Vein IS made of three layers or vein made of three layers?

Tags: grammar

What is the right way of the following two?

> 1. Vein IS made of three layers.
> 2. Vein made of three layers.

Comment: Do you intend your examples to be complete sentences? Or are they phrases that would go inside a larger sentence?

Comment: Please allow at least a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. For info about why this is helpful, please see “[Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct as a complete sentence. You could say

1. Veins are made of three layers.
2. The vein is made of three layers.
3. A vein is made of three layers.

All three of these would be understood the same way. In 2 and 3, the singular is used but it is understood that the statement applies to all veins.